# Как удалить из предложения символы псевдографики?

Tags: pascalabc.net

Не понимаю как сделать условие проверки каждого символа на псевдографику (176-223 символы), удалить их, вывести исправленное предложение и посчитать разность исходного предложения и полученного.

Вот мой код:

```
program pr11;
uses crt;

procedure ms(var s,s1: string; var r:byte);
var
  i:integer;
begin
  while i < length(s) do begin
    i:=i+1;

    if ord(s[i]) in [176..223] then delete (s,i,1)
  end;
end;

var
  s, s1:string;
  r:byte;
begin
  writeln('Введите предложение: ');
  readln(s);

  ms(s,s1,r);

  writeln(' разность= ',r);

  writeln('Изменённое предложение: ', s);
end.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
i := 1;
while i <= Length(s) do begin
  if ord(s[i]) in [176..223] then
    Delete(s, i, 1)
  else
    i := i + 1;
end;
```

> разность исходного предложения и полученного

это что?

Comment: Разность не нужно, сам доделаю, нужно чтобы после ввода предложения из букв и символов псевдографики он редактировал его и оставлял только буквы

Comment: например введем предложение : hello ═╠╬═

Comment: @ЕвгенийЕремеев Так написал уже.

Comment: но он не удаляет псевдографику из предложения...

Comment: все уже перепробовал

Comment: может проблема не с процедурой, а с тем что идет на вывод?

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю вам вот такой вариант - не удалять символы из строки, а сразу помещать их в две строки результата - очищенная строка (`r1`) и с разностью в виде убранных символов (`r`)

```
program pr11;
uses crt;

procedure RemovePD(const s: string; s1, r: string);
var
  i: integer;
begin
   s1 := '';
   r := '';
   for i := 1 to Length(s) do
     if Ord(s[i]) in [176..223] then
       r := r + s[i]
     else
       s1 := s1 + s[i];
   end;
end;

var
  s, s1, r: string;
begin
  writeln('Введите предложение: ');
  readln(s);

  RemovePD(s,s1,r);

  writeln(' разность= ', r);

  writeln('Изменённое предложение: ', s1);
end.
```